# How to connect to a specific AP in case of having duplicates?

Tags: windows-8.1, wireless-access-point

I'm looking for a way to distinguish APs which have the same names in Windows 8.1. There are about 3 APs that have the same name and I'm looking for a way to connect to only one of them but Windows randomly lists only one of them each time I check for available APs using charm menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect to your AP by Mac-address not the SSID
There is a lot of programs there, that will let you scan for WiFi networks and connect to them by specific Mac address, even you can check if there is hidden networks to connect with.

try this program  CommonView it's simple
[image]

- or "wirlessmoon"
- or "wireshark"

If you don't like that, change the channel for each AP that's will work in some cases

Comment: CommonView has some problems with my Wireless network adapter, the search for AP button is disabled. Wirelessmon doesn't automatically detect the network's setup and it asks me to enter security information of each network and it's a bit confusing so I just entered security info it showed about the AP. I couldn't manage to find any information about connecting to an AP in Wireshark.

Comment: WireShark and CommView not that simple, and it will take time to find the driver, anyway, try wirelessmon it's very simple, and this is the [download page](http://wirelessmon.en.softonic.com/) enjoy :) If you need help in wirelessmon let me know, sorry I didn't understand what you mean about security information?

Comment: Thank you, Wirelessmon is so simple, nothing rouge about it. security information like encryption method, like WEP, WPA or WPA2, and for WPA, there are TKIP, and AES.